# Proper workflow for model selection and hyperparameter tuning using cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-selection

I have been trying to teach myself about machine learning and wanted to make sure I had the right idea about model selection, hyperparameter tuning, and cross validation.

So given a data set, my understanding is that this is the general workflow should be.
1. Split into train and test
2. Use cross validation on training set to select model
3. After picking a model then perform hyperparameter tuning with cross validation

Is that correct? Also, for step 3, should tuning be done with the whole data set or just the test set?

Comment: Hyperparameter tuning *is* (one type of) model selection, so I don't understand your proposed setup. (Nevertheless, I am not the -1 vote.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Knowing what is problematic with one's thought processes is the first step to learning! For clarification, does picking the type of model (random forest, SVM, etc) and hyperparameter tuning both need to happen before doing any narrowing down of models? Or does one type of selection happen before the other?

Answer (score 0):

Like a Russian Matryoshka doll, there can be many layers of data partitioning and model selection you can use with a dataset. For a "simple" approach, you can first partition your data into train and test sets. Within your training set, you can use cross validation to choose the best hyperparameters for each model. Once you choose your best hyperparameters, you can see how well the model with those hyperparameters performs on the test set. You can repeat this process to build models with many approaches, such as a linear model, random forest, SVM, etc. The model that performs best on the test set will be your "best" model to deploy.

To be clear: you do NOT tune on the test set. This would lead to overfitting. You would simply use the test set to compare a few different models. However, the more you look at the test set, the more risk of overfitting.